# Slow Join on Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in sql server with a join that is taking forever.  I'm hoping someone might have a tip to speed it up.

I think the problem is I'm joining on a field called Reseller_CSN which has values like '_0070000050'

I've tried using the substring function in the join to return everything but underscore, example '0070000050' but I keep getting an error when I try to cast or convert the result to int or bigint.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, the query is below:

```
   SELECT         
            t1.RESELLER_CSN 
           ,t1.FIRST_YEAR_RENEWAL
           ,t1.SEAT_SEGMENT
           ,t2.Target_End_Date_CY
           ,t2.Target_End_Date_PQ
           ,t2.Target_End_Date_CY_1
           ,t2.Target_End_Date_CY_2
           ,t1.ASSET_SUB_END_DATE
    FROM   dbo.new_all_renewals t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.new_all_renewals_vwTable t2 
    ON  SUBSTRING(t1.RESELLER_CSN,2,11) = SUBSTRING(t2.RESELLER_CSN,2,11)
```

Comment: Execution plan please? Did you look at it? Without that we can only  guess.

Comment: The Substring is a join is a very very very bad idea. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

A join on processed columns invariably takes more effort than a join on raw columns.  In this case, you can improve performance by using computed columns.   For instance, on the first table, you can do:

```
alter table new_all_renewals add CSN_num as SUBSTRING(t1.RESELLER_CSN,2,11);
create index on new_all_renewals(CSN_num);
```

This will generate an index on the column, which should speed the query.  (Note:  you'll need to reference the computed column rather than actually using the function.)

Comment: Maybe make it a persisted computed column? I was just wondering what the speed difference would be. Have any ideas on that? From my memory a computed column is computed when requested.

Comment: Indexes should be allowed on these computed columns.  You can refresh your memory here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292(v=sql.110).aspx.

Comment: I thought that the optimizer was smart enough to say "hey, that function that you're calling ad hoc has the same definition as this computed column that I have, so I'll use the computed column". Am I off on this?

Comment: @BenThul . . . Yes, that is true (virtual column indexes are equivalent to function-based indexes).  I take the more cautious approach, just in case the optimizer doesn't agree with what I think should be the same.